# Анимация исчезновения на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть очень маленький кусок кода, который нужно доделать на jQuery, не пойму, что за проблема: 1 этап появления анимации есть, а второго этапа исчезновения не могу добится, оно почему-то читает код не так, как я задумал. Гляньте пример и вы поймете. То, что закомментировано в jQuery откройте.

**Пример**: http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/28/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сначала скрываете элемент, а затем проигрываете анимацию. Нужно наоборот. Вот рабочий вариант:

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    $('#triggermap').click(function() {
        var map = $(".schememap");

        map.stop(); // stop animation if running

        if(map.is(':visible')) {
            map.animate({ right:493, opacity: 0 }, 1200, function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        }
        else
            map.show().animate({ right:193, opacity: 1 }, 1200);        
    }); 
});
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/29/

Comment: повторный клик во время анимации не учитывается. будет некрасиво. вид текущей анимации надо запоминать, видимостью не отделаться.

Comment: Необязательно, думаю дело вкуса. Остановки активной анимации вполне достаточно. Тем не менее интересно увидеть Ваш вариант.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov  и @Павел Азанов [так примерно ?](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ad8zr/30/)

Comment: @eicto, да именно так. Напрасно все-таки убрали toggle из jquery, приходится извращаться.

Comment: я думаю ещё пару штук уберут с одинаковыми именами.

Comment: ну альтернативу надо было какую-то предложить, и обратная совместимость страдает. в общем неудобно и код разрастается.

Comment: для обратной совместимости есть [Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)